# What part of the certificate creation process needs to remain the same for an iOS app?

Tags: ios, ssl-certificate

I have an app in the app store, made using Phonegap Build.

I now need to add push notification support to it, so have had to create and download a new .cer file on the Apple Dev site. I then need to make a p12 from that, and add that with my provisioning profile to my Phonegap Build signing keys.

What I'm wondering, is if I build the app with this new signing key, can it still be submitted as an update for my app store app, or will Apple see this as a new app now?

If the answer is yes, which of the following needs to stat the same in order for Apple to accept it as an app update, and not a brand new app?

.key file
.cer file
.p12 file

Thank you.

Comment: app update is considered by adding a a new version of the existing application in the app store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the bundle identifier is the same, it will be the same app in the store.
The full bundle identifier consists of some hash for your Apple account + the identifier part in the project settings, usually something like: abc123.com.yourcompany.projectname

Answer (score -1):

.key, .cer and .p12 can change.
All you have to do is to keep the same bundle identifier so that Apple will consider it as an update of an existing app.

Comment: Doesn't the .key file have to be the same, otherwise you cannot sign binaries with it? http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/90538-critical-back-up-your-developer-key.html - or is the key you create when you make your apps different to your developer key?

Comment: As long as it's still your original developer account, it doesn't matter as you can only have one distribution key at all times. If you recreate it, that one will be your key for the following updates and so on.